# Wordpress added mp3 to root folder but can't hear audio

Tags: wordpress, mp3

I have an mp3 file (song.mp3) that I added to my root WP install so I can go to *example.com/song* or *example.com/song.mp3* and be able to simply listen to that file.

I've added it to the site and I get a music player but I don't hear any audio. Is there another step?

Comment: Can you please provide the link ??

Comment: Yes, sorry, [here you go](http://www.healthyogalife.com/mind-mood-muscle-audio-meditation-sample)

Comment: What it has to do with wordpress ???

Comment: You're right it doesn't. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I can see it working. May be you are having a browser issue. Try using a different browser. Or check if .mp3's are not blocked on your network or machine. Please check back again. Tell me if I missed anything..

Comment: Are you able to hear anything? I am not.

Comment: I can listen to the voice of a lady... Your speakers are all right? did you checked the volume of your machine ??

Comment: Okay then that's good.My speakers work, I'll troubleshoot knowing it's actually working. Thank you.

Comment: I have a similar questions. On [this page](http://www.healthyogalife.com/mind-mood-muscle-online-yoga-sampletips) my image is 900px wide, what is the reason it changes the width, to load it faster?

Comment: That is because the height of the image is more and just to accommodate the image browser displays it in zoom out format..